# React component not re-rendering on component state change

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a sidebar using a recursive function to populate a nested list of navigation items.

Functionally, everything works except for the re-render when I click on one of the list items to toggle the visibility of the child list.

Now, when I expand or collapse the sidebar (the parent component with its visibility managed in its own state), the list items then re-render as they should. This shows me the state is being updated.

I have a feeling this possibly has something to do with the recursive function?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import styles from "./SidebarList.module.css";

function SidebarList(props) {
  const { data } = props;

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState([]);

  const toggleVisibility = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.innerHTML;

    if (visible.includes(value)) {
      setVisible((prev) => {
        let index = prev.indexOf(value);
        let newArray = prev;
        newArray.splice(index, 1);
        return newArray;
      });
    } else {
      setVisible((prev) => {
        let newArray = prev;
        newArray.push(value);
        return newArray;
      });
    }
  };

  const hasChildren = (item) => {
    return Array.isArray(item.techniques) && item.techniques.length > 0;
  };

  const populateList = (data) => {
    return data.map((object) => {
      return (
        <>
          <li
            key={object.name}
            onClick={(e) => toggleVisibility(e)}
          >
            {object.name}
          </li>

          {visible.includes(object.name) ? (
            <ul id={object.name}>
              {hasChildren(object) && populateList(object.techniques)}
            </ul>
          ) : null}
        </>
      );
    });
  };

  let list = populateList(data);

  return <ul>{list}</ul>;
}

export default SidebarList;
```

Comment: What recursive function?

Comment: If you dig into the populateList function, I am conditionally rendering the nested list of items if they exist. This is calling the populateList function again and returning null on a false condition.

Comment: You didn't explain what is it that doesn't work and also you didn't provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which makes it difficult to help you. My guess is that `visible.includes(value)` will always return `false` because you're trying to compare objects, but that may be just one of the problems this code has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many anti patterns with this code but I will just focus on rendering issue. Arrays hold order. Your state does not need to be ordered so it's easier to modify it, for the case of demo I will use object. Your toggle method gets event, but you want to get DOM value. That's not necessary, you could just sent your's data unique key.

See [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-neumann-f37eqj?file=/src/App.js) as it fixes the issues I mentioned above.

Comment: This did it... Thanks for the feedback on the anti-patterns as well. I've only been learning for a few months and been on react for about a month, so I'm sure there are many better ways to format.